# Regex match if not before and after

Tags: python, regex

How can I match 'suck' only if not part of 'honeysuckle'?

Using lookbehind and lookahead I can match suck if not 'honeysuck' or 'suckle', but it also fails to catch something like 'honeysucker'; here the expression *should* match, because it doesn't end in `le`:

```
re.search(r'(?<!honey)suck(?!le)', 'honeysucker')
```

Comment: The goal is to match all instances of "suck" that are not instances of "honeysuckle". Sorry if it's not clear...

Comment: The goal is to match if a string contains "suck" AND NOT "honeysuckle". We could argue about why someone would want to do this forever, but that doesn't address the question of whether it's possible to do with a regular expression.

Comment: Okay, I *think* what you are asking (and which is not clear) is why does `'honeysucker'` *not* match, but it should *because* it ends in `er`. You are making it sound the other way around. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: This is a hard one, because look-arounds are independent. Finding words that are not part of a *specific* larger word is not a problem I'd solve with regular expressions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You can make them dependent of each other by placing the lookahead assertion inside the lookbehind (or vice versa).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to nest the lookaround assertions:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"(?<!honey(?=suckle))suck")
>>> regex.search("honeysuckle")
>>> regex.search("honeysucker")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000029B6370>
>>> regex.search("suckle")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000029B63D8>
>>> regex.search("suck")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000029B6370>
```

An equivalent solution would be `suck(?!(?<=honeysuck)le)`.

Answer (score 2):

here is a solution without using regular expressions:

```
s = s.replace('honeysuckle','')
```

and now:

```
re.search('suck',s)
```

and this would work for any of these strings : `honeysuckle sucks`, `this sucks` and even `regular expressions suck`.

Comment: You need `re.findall()` to "match all instances of 'suck'"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should separate your exceptions in a different Array, just in case in the future you wish to add a different rule. This will be easier to read, and will be faster in the future to change if needed.

My suggestion in Ruby is:

```
words = ['honeysuck', 'suckle', 'HONEYSUCKER', 'honeysuckle']

EXCEPTIONS = ['honeysuckle']

def match_suck word
  if (word =~ /suck/i) != nil
    # should not match any of the exceptions
    return true unless EXCEPTIONS.include? word.downcase
  end
  false
end

words.each{ |w|
  puts "Testing match of '#{w}' : #{match_suck(w)}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>string = 'honeysucker'
>>>print 'suck' in string
True
```